# How to create Selenium IDE which works on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I want to create a selenium IDE for IE which is similar to IDE on Firefox.
It is fine if it does not playback, but it should be able to identify locators of the objects.

Comment: What is the question?. What have you got so far?

Comment: I want to write an add-on for internet explorer that will help me identify locators for selenium. just like selenium IDE works for firefox